# Why am I getting error "invalid matchOutcome for participant"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

I am trying to end my 2 player turn-based game after the current player quits with this code:

```
NSUInteger currentIndex = [match.participants indexOfObject:match.currentParticipant];
GKTurnBasedParticipant *curr = match.currentParticipant;
GKTurnBasedParticipant *next = [match.participants objectAtIndex:(currentIndex + 1)%[match.participants count]];

[match participantQuitInTurnWithOutcome:GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit
                           nextParticipants:@[next]
                                turnTimeout:MAXFLOAT
                                  matchData:matchData
                          completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                              if (error) {
                                  NSLog(@"%@", error);
                              }


                              [curr setMatchOutcome:GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit];
                              [next setMatchOutcome:GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeWon];

                              [match endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:matchData
                                               completionHandler:nil
```

However I'm getting the error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'invalid matchOutcome for participant'

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Re-update your match by calling the class func "loadMatchWithID:"

then call "endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:" after setting the matchOutcome of each participants.

You might be getting this error "reason: 'invalid matchOutcome for participant'" because your data is out of sync.

alternative ------------>
Or you could just use "endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:" since it will result in same output, just make sure to update any necessary data needed.